# Can I wrap a video as material on a blender object?

Tags: uv, video

I am new to blender. I want to wrap a 360 video around a sphere in blender. I tried doing so but instead of wrapping the video, only a single frame was wrapped. Can some one please help me as to how I can get the video to play on the sphere?

Comment: Yes I did. Didn't seem to help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xTzJIaKQFY This was the link I used to map the video. It explains for an image, but I simply selected an mp4 file instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

In **Cycles**, in your Material Image Texture Node, make sure you enter the ***Number of Frames*** and the ***Start Frame*** of the video you want Blender to extract.  ***Movie*** should be selected automatically.  Check the ***Cyclic*** and ***Auto Refresh***  checkboxes (**Note:** You must be in *Rendered Mode* to see the frame advance with Cycles.).

> **Auto Refresh**:  Automatically refresh images on frame changes.
>
> **Cyclic**: Start over and repeats after the last frame to create a continuous loop.

[image]

---

In **BI**, it's the same process but it's under Textures (the gif above was rendered using Blender Render). **Note:** *Texture* and *Material Mode* seem to work fine with frame advance in BI as well as *Rendered*:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer. But i am still facing a few problems. Even after I do this, the video doesn't play. Is there something I could be missing, I'll just write down what ever I've done so far. 

1. Add a UV sphere.
2. Marked seam along a longitude.
3. UV unwrapped it to a rectangle.
4. Added the material from the Material Image Texture Node.
5. Entered the required no. of frames and ticked the two options. 

I still do not see anything happening. I used a mp4 video.

Comment: @AbhyudayPuri - Are you using Cycles or BI?  Are you displaying in Rendered mode or Texture/Material mode (must be rendered)?  Do you have the Offset set to "0"?  I tested with MP4 and it still works so I doubt it's the format.

Comment: I am using Cycles Render. After adding the video as material around the sphere, I was viewing it in the object mode. I did put the offset to -1. I also rendered the video by using the animation option, but the output didn't show any movement. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @AbhyudayPuri - I don't really know what else to say.  I've done this with multiple videos and formats in both cycles and BI, this is a known process.  Maybe it's a compatibility issue?  I'm using 2.78c.  Here's a **working** .blend with an MP4 video for you to try: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6awryf4234g8em/movie%20wrap.zip?dl=0  Just press **Shift** + **Z** to go into Rendered view and then click on the timeline pane to move to different frames.  You should see the material update with each frame.

Comment: okay. Thanks for all your help! I'll try the process again. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Hey @bertmoog, I got that working! :D I really appreciate your help. Could you help me with one last thing? I want the blender camera to be able to move and view the video playing on the sphere, and then render that as my final output. How can I do that?

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I have accepted this answer. Very well explained. :)

Comment: @AbhyudayPuri - So glad you got everything working :)

Comment: One problem that i face currently is, as is even scene in the video that you've wrapped around the sphere. There are square patches which are very easily observable. How can I ensure that those do not appear in my final rendered output? @bertmoog Could you help  me with this too

Comment: @AbhyudayPuri - I'm not sure what you mean by "square patches".  In the video itself or on your object?

Comment: As you can see in the video that you have uploaded, the mesh lines are still visible. That is what i am referring to as square patches.

Comment: @AbhyudayPuri - Just enable **Smooth Shading** or add a **Subsurf Modifier** to the mesh or both.  If it still looks "blocky" after that, it's probably compression artifacts in your video.